# Getting processing time in Julius

Tags: speech-recognition

The idea is to get an estimate of how much processing time is required by Julius for every second of speech.

Using `Recog *recog` it is straightforward to determine how long the speech was via `(float)recog->speechlen / (float)recog->jconf->input.sfreq` but I can't find anywhere where it indicates how much processing time it required.

Has anyone tackled this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `callback_add` with events `CALLBACK_EVENT_RECOGNITION_BEGIN` and `CALLBACK_EVENT_RECOGNITION_END`. Save the initial time when it begins, then the difference when it ends is the duration.